# How to enable/disable Android Studio from jumping to the first error after build

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I try to write some code... while at it the auto build kicks in (or I just manually build) since this action can take some time, I go on typing...

As soon as the build is done, and when it finds errors it just opens the file of the first error and jumps to the error line where I go on typing there...

Where is the off switch for that feature, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@yole was pretty close...

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler -> Automatically show first error in editor.

Why things has to be so cryptic???

Comment: Does this actually work for anyone? I unchecked this box, invalidated cache, restarted, but the editor still jumps to (in my case completely unrelated due to data binding import issues) the first error

Comment: It does not work for me.
My IntelliJ version is Build #IU-222.4345.14, built on October 5, 2022

Answer (score 1):

Settings | Compiler | Automatically show first error in editor

Comment: Android Studio does not have a Compiler - only a '**Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)**' And that one doesn't have that option...